# Displaying an Image from controller <dotnet>

Tags: javascript, .net, image

My code is very simple: I'm retrieving an image from database then passing it from the controller as a string (I think) to the view.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult photo()
{
        using (Trial01Context db = new Trial01Context())
        {
            byte[] img = db.Employees.Find(5).file;

            if (img == null)
            {
                @ViewBag.msg = "IMG is NULL !";
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("\""+"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img)+"\"");
            }
        }
}
```

View markup:

```
<img id="whatever" src="/ControllerName/photo" />
```

but all I got is a corrupted image!

If I put the value returned by the controller in a `ViewBag.img` for example and change view to

```
<img id="whatever" src="@ViewBag.img" />
```

then it works fine.

Comment: what is the problem with having it in the viewbag?

Comment: the problem is that i'm working in a project and this is just an exemple of a simple part of it. In the real thing I need to call a methode i cant use ViewBag

Comment: You can set the model and pass it to the view

Comment: The image is in a popup and i cant change the code allready existing my job (or part of it) is to make the popup show this image so i cant use nor models nor Viewbags i think

Answer (score 0):

I think it works without the backslashes: \

```
return Content("data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the following :

return File(img, "image/png") ; 
in the controller and , 
img  src="/Controller/Methode"  
in the View.